# In git, given two branches, how do I find the point at which one branch was merged into the other?

Tags: git, git-merge

If I have two branches, and one has been merged into the other, how can I find, from the command line and without manual inspection, in which commit the merge happened?

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry about previous answer, read question entirely wrong.)

You have a situation in which you're on branch `curbranch` (at commit `HEAD`, but let's just use `curbranch` below), and you believe that branch `other` was merged into `curbranch` in the past.  As in the linked question, the trick is to specify merge commits that are ancestors of `curbranch` but are descendents of `other`.  Per the [git-rev-list documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html), that's `--ancestry-path other..curbranch --merges` (which you can pass to `git log`, etc, or run in a script to extract SHA1 values and do further processing on them).

There are some minor issues with this.  Specifically, just because something is in that ancestry path and is a merge does not mean it was a merge of `other` into `curbranch`.  For instance, perhaps `other` was merged into `accumulator` and then later `accumulator` was merged into `curbranch`:

```
..- B - C - D - E - F  <-- curbranch
              /
..- G - H - I          <-- accumulator
      /
..- J                  <-- other
```

Here, both commits `H` and `E` are (1) a descendent of `other`, (2) an ancestor of `curbranch`, and (3) a merge.  You will see both commits.  That may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
git log --merges --oneline
```

It will print only the merge commits.

Comment: You should probably change `--online` to `--oneline`